# Complex line integral without using Cauchy Integral Formula.

Tags: complex-analysis

The integral $$\displaystyle\int _C \dfrac{2z-1}{z^2-z}dz$$ 
and the $C:=\{z| |z|<1/2\}$

Obviously $$\displaystyle\int_C \dfrac{2z-1}{z^2-z}dz=\ln(z^2-z)|_C$$ but I think I cannot use this formula because $\dfrac{2z-1}{z^2-z}$ is not analytic inside the contour $C$ right?

So I can split the $\dfrac{2z-1}{z^2-z}$ and say that the analytic part is zero and for the other one I can simply use the parametrization of C and calculate.

$\dfrac{2z-1}{z^2-z}=\dfrac{1}{z-1}+\dfrac{1}{z}$

The contour C doesnot include $z=1$ so $\displaystyle\int_C\dfrac{1}{z-1}=0$, start and end points are the same.

and for the $\displaystyle\int_C\dfrac{1}{z}$ one, I can use the parametrization of the circle $C$ as $C(t)=\dfrac12e^{it}$, $t\in[0,2\pi)$

so
$$\displaystyle\int_C\dfrac{1}{z}=0$$

$z=\dfrac12e^{it}$ and so $dz=\dfrac i2 e^{it}dt$

so

$$\displaystyle\int_C\dfrac{1}{z}=\displaystyle\int_C\dfrac{i/2e^{it}}{2e^{it}}dt=\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}i=2\pi$$

But it is stuck in my throat because I feel like I am doing things circularly. Because if I were to use the parametrization for the whole function I would get the following but to calculate it I again use the information that this integral is $ln(z^2-z)$

$$\displaystyle\int _C \dfrac{2z-1}{z^2-z}dz$$ if I apply the parametrization.

$$\displaystyle\int _C \dfrac{2z-1}{z^2-z}dz\to\dfrac i2\displaystyle\int _C \dfrac{2\frac12e^{it}-1}{\frac14e^{2it}-\frac12e^{it}}e^{it}dt\to 2i\displaystyle\int _C\dfrac{e^{it}-1}{e^{it}-2}dt$$
and I dont know how to calculate the last integral directly, because if I were to make substitution I again gets the result $ln(z^2-z)$ thats why I call it circular.

What is the proper method to calculate this kind of complex line integrals, without using Cauchy integral formula.